# How the sum of the following geometric series is calculated.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I know that the sum in the following picture is a finite geometric series, and I know that the formula for calculating it is $$s_{n} = \frac{a-ar^{n}}{1-r}$$, where a is the first term and r is the ratio. But how is this applied in the second term in the numerator of the last equality in the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y = e^{ix}$ then the constants around the series multiply to $$\frac{4}{\pi} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{\pi}$$ and the series itself looks like
$$
y^{-2N+1} + y^{-2N+3} + \ldots + y^{2N-1}
 = y^{-2N+1} \left[ 1 + y^2 + y^4 + \ldots + y^{4N-2}\right]
$$
and now you can clearly see that the first term is $a = y^{-2N+1}$, the common factor is $r = y^2$ and the last term is $ar^{n-1} = y^{4N-2}$, which means that the final sum would be
$$
\frac{2}{\pi} \frac{a-ar^n}{1-r}
 = \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{y^{-2N+1} - y^{2N+1}}{1-y^2}
 = \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{e^{ix(-2N+1)} - e^{ix(2N+1)}}{1-e^{2ix}}
$$

Comment: No, I do not understand why u wrote the series like this? and I want to know if the formula I stated for calculating finite geometric is right or wrong?  I am not sure that the finite series you mentioned above will give the same result as that stated in the picture the first term will be $e^{2ix(-2N +1)}$ which is not what is mentioned.

Comment: @weakmathematician i wrote them like this so it would be easy for you to see what the first term is, and what the last term is, so you can plug the result into your $s_n$ formula

Comment: but there is an extra 2 in the power of each term.

Comment: @weakmathematician updated, fixed, made clearer

Comment: I think that $ar^{n-1}$ is not right..... could u please check it?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know is

$$r^p+r^{p+1}+r^{p+2}+...r^{q} =$$

$$r^p\frac {1-r^{q+1-p}}{1-r} $$

which you apply with

$$r=e^{ix} $$
$$p=-2N+1$$
$$q=2N-1$$

Comment: the ratio is not $e^{2ix}, it is $e^{ix} $

Comment: but the picture did not say this.... is it a mistake?

Comment: @weakmathematician Yes of course. where $2$ come from.

Comment: from where did you get the rule that you mentioned in first equality? do you have a proof for it?

Comment: I feel that the second term in the numerator of the r.h.s of your first equality is not right could you verify it please?

Comment: @weakmathematician the exponent is exactly the number of terms in the sum which is $q-p+1$